# Ordering following recursive foreignkey

Tags: django, django-models

Working on django flatpages, I found this ressource :
[Bending django flatpages to your will](http://linfiniti.com/2011/01/bending-django-flatpages-to-your-will/)

Found it usefull, but I can't figure out how the ExtendedFlatPages are getting ordered. In other words, i can't understand :

```
flatPages = ExtendedFlatPage.objects.filter(child_of__isnull=True).order_by('-show_after')
```

the model is defined as follows :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
class ExtendedFlatPage(FlatPage):
    show_after = models.ForeignKey('ExtendedFlatPage', null=True, blank=True, default=None )
    child_of = models.ForeignKey('ExtendedFlatPage', null=True, blank=True, default=None )
```

I find this way of doing elegant, as you don't need to use a dedicated field to order the ExtendedFlatPage, but can't find the logic below this.

Answer (score 0):

The order as you have it isn't particularly useful.  You're going to end up ordered by show_after.id, which would just be an auto increment int.

Comment: Thank you for the answer... So I'm right, it doesn't work, does it ? The point seemed to be able to order pages by specifying the previous one for each page, and probably None for the first. I also came to the conclusion that ordering by show_after.id wasn't doing the trick. Btw this guy seems to use it successfully, so I was wondering if there was a kind of "magic" I couldn't see...